# ImageView ScaleType ignores padding

Tags: android, gridview, imageview, border

I have a Imageview set with a white background and 1dp padding, this creates a border-like effect, which is the wanted result.

Now if I set the scaleType to centerCrop it ignores the padding on the top and bottom.
So I still have my border on the left and right side, but not on the top and bottom.

Anyone with an idea to stop this from happening?
Or another quick way to create a border around images. I use it for my custom gridview

```
   <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            android:contentDescription="@string/test"
            android:padding="1dp"
            android:src="@drawable/some_photo"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

Comment: android:scaleType="fitxy" check

Comment: No that will stretch the image, I'm trying to prevent that

Comment: also set android:adjustViewBounds="true" and still it stretch image than instead of using android:src use android:background

Answer (score -9, accepted):

I just encountered the same problem, for my workaround will be adding the android:layout_marginRight="5dip"

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#ffffffff"
    android:src="@drawable/liveview_logo"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dip"/>
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked, I thought I couldn't use a extra linearlayout in a gridView, turns out I can.

Comment: won't be feasible in all cases. Manolo Garcia has the right answer

Comment: the answer from Manolo Garcia is the right one, this margin right does not make sense..

Comment: This is not the correct answer, Manolo Garcia's solution is correct.

Answer (score 176):

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:contentDescription="@string/test"
    android:padding="1dp"
    android:src="@drawable/some_photo"
    android:cropToPadding="true"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop" />
```

You only need to add [android:cropToPadding](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#attr_android:cropToPadding)

> android:cropToPadding="true"

and then the imageView is going to respect the padding that you choose.

Comment: note: that the attribute has been present since api level 1, but the method has only been available since JellyBean.

Comment: On Android 4.4.2 also with android:cropToPadding="true" it does not work, if you set a background resource after setting the padding. So you have first to set the background resource and then set the padding.
See Matt McMinn's answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15060962/676945

Answer (score 2):

You can give border by setting `android:background="@drawable/edit_border"`

And your edit_border:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >

    <stroke
        android:width="2dp"
        android:color="#EBDDE2" />

    <padding
        android:bottom="2dp"
        android:left="2dp"
        android:right="2dp"
        android:top="4dp" />

    <gradient
        android:centerColor="@color/white" 
        android:endColor="@color/white"
        android:startColor="@color/white" />

    <corners android:radius="8dp" />

</shape>
```

Comment: Did get the border but the portrait pictures in my landscape Imageviews still don't show the top and bottom border

Answer (score 0):

@Manolo Garcia's Answer is correct.
That helped me in dynamic imageview using border, Scale Type Center Crop and padding.

```
final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
LinearLayout.LayoutParams lp = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(200,200);
lp.setMargins(0, 0, 10, 0);
imageView.setLayoutParams(lp);
imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
imageView.setCropToPadding(true);
imageView.setScaleType(ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP);
imageView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.img_blue_border);
imageView.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
```