# selectableItemBackground not working for Android 4.4.2 Device

Tags: android, onclick, android-drawable

I am trying to set the `onClick()` highlight for each row in my `TableLayout`.

I have a drawable resource file:

```
<item
    android:drawable="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
    android:state_focused="true"
    android:state_pressed="true" />

<!-- Bottom border -->
<item android:top="65dp" android:left="15dp">
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
        <size android:height="0.25dp"/>
        <solid android:color="@color/dark_blue"/>
    </shape>
</item>
```

I have tested this on a Samsung Galaxy S5 device which works.
However, when I test on a ZTE Compel Device, which has Android 4.4.2 installed on it -- it does not work.

My application is targeting API 15 and up.

Any ideas why this: `?android:attr/selectableItemBackground` doesn't work on Android 4.4.2 device?

Error in logs:

> Caused by: org.xmlpull.v1.XmlPullParserException: Binary XML file line #7:  tag requires a 'drawable' attribute or child tag defining a drawable

I have `?attr/selectableItemBackground` and it doesn't resolve the issue.
I have done a ton of research.

Any other suggestions from your side?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19714682/android-apply-selectableitembackground-in-xml-with-support-v7

Comment: I've already looked at that page on Stackoverflow. It doesn't solve my issue. @KristyWelsh

Comment: Looks like a theming-related issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was in my drawable Resource File I was using a layer-list. Drawable attribute in a layer-list (or state-list) does not accept an attr value.

However, I couldn't set this attr value in my layout file because I also needed a bottom border for each table row.

So to fix this, in the Java Class file:

I retrieve a reference to each row in my onCreate() method.

Example: 
`TableRow row1 = (TableRow)findViewById(R.id.table_row_1);`

Then I created a method that would handle adding the attribute to the bottom_border drawable file:

```
`void setRowHighlight(TableRow row) {
    // Attribute array
    int[] attrs = new int[] { android.R.attr.selectableItemBackground };

    TypedArray a = getTheme().obtainStyledAttributes(attrs);

    // Drawable held by attribute 'selectableItemBackground' is at index '0'
    Drawable d = a.getDrawable(0);

    a.recycle();

    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 16) {
        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {

                // Table Rows Border Drawable
                getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.table_rows_border),

                // Drawable from attribute
                d });

        // Set the background to 'ld'
        row.setBackgroundDrawable(ld);
    } else {
        LayerDrawable ld = new LayerDrawable(new Drawable[] {

                // Table Rows Border Drawable
                ResourcesCompat.getDrawable(getResources(), R.drawable.table_rows_border, null),

                // Drawable from attribute
                d });

        // Set the background to 'ld'
        row.setBackground(ld);
    }

}`
```

Enable the row highlight, call my method in the onCreate():
`setRowHighlight(row1);`

I have tested this on my Samsung Galaxy S5 device (Android 5.0) and ZTE Compel device (Android 4.4.2) and it works.

Reference: [?android:attr/selectableItemBackground with another existing background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269910/androidattr-selectableitembackground-with-another-existing-background)